# Get iframeId created by chrome -- not the HTML `Id` attribute

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

How do I get iframeId created by chrome?
I am not referring to the `Id` attribute

I am building a chrome extension to access an Iframe and this is a bottleneck for me.

[This link says](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#property-detailsType-frameId) `0` is assigned to the mainframe and a positive value indicates subframes.

I want to get that positive value (ID) for the subframes.

Comment: Could be chrome.webNavigation.getAllFrames depending on how you want to use it.